# unable to navigate back using arrow keys input text box

Tags: jquery, textfield

I have an input text box for which special characters are restricted using the following jquery event

```
$(":input").bind("keyup blur", function(){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,'') );
});
```

Now, the issue is that once after filling the field with some data, i'm unable to navigate back using the arrow keys. this restriction is seen in chrome and ie. in firefox its is fine. i need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Try this, this might help!!

$("[id$='<%=txtConfPwd.ClientID%>']").keyup(function () {

```
      if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) 
         {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
                return;
         }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked for me

```
    $(":input").bind("keyup blur", function(){
        if(e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 39) {
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,'') );
        }
    });
```